# Create() fails in MediaPlayer - android

Tags: android, callback, media-player

I am trying to play a few music (wav format) files based on button clicks. I am unable to get MediaPlayer to work properly. Every time I try to instantiate an object of MediaPlayer class, it fails on create(). Before I post the code, here is a run-through of what I am doing:
1. A layout file that contains 2 buttons.
2. Those buttons are read and onClickListeners defined for them.
3. Depending on the button clicked, a function called `playAudioFile(View)` called which creates the MediaPlayer instance and plays the file. The code for playAudioFile(View) is as follows:

```
   public void playAudioFile(View v) {
        /*Steps:
         * 1. Take in id of the button.
         * 2. Using id, identify what file needs to be played.
         * 3. Play file.
         */

        String path_to_file = null;   //this is the path to the file.

        if(b01.getId() == ((Button)v).getId()) {
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Button 01 pressed.");
            path_to_file = "/sdcard/audio/temp1.wav";
        } else if(b02.getId() == ((Button)v).getId()) {
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Button02 pressed.");
            path_to_file = "/sdcard/audio/temp2.wav";
        }
        path_to_file = "file://" + path_to_file;
        Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(path_to_file);
        Log.v(this.toString(), "Path of file = " + path_to_file);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, streamUri);

        if(mp == null) {
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Create() on MediaPlayer failed.");
        }

        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Illegal state exception thrown in start.");
                }
            }
        });

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    }
```

I have gone through a lot of posts here on stackoverflow that detail solutions to the above problem. I am encountering this problem after having incorporated all the suggestions made therein. Any help is most welcome.

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: i think you are adding extra \ before filepath

Comment: @chirag: if i was adding an extra \ before the file path, then should the mediaplayer not have failed on setDataSource()? Why on prepare()? I will try out the suggestion you made.

Comment: @chirag: no, removing a '\' before filepath does not change anything. thanks!

Comment: dis any of the comments solve your problem?

Comment: @gian1200: not really.. i dont know what the problem was.. but the moment i restarted the computer, everything fell into place.

Answer (score 2):

I dont understand why you are trying to do

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, streamUri);
```

This is my implementation of my Player, Hope this will help you in some way:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        setContentView(R.layout.player);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String path = "";

        System.out.println("My Scheme : "+intent.getData().toString().substring(8));

        if (intent.getData().getScheme().equals("video")) {

            path = intent.getData().toString().substring(8);
            System.out.println("Path : "+path);

            if(path.endsWith(".mp3")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.musicplayer);
            setContentView(R.layout.controls);

                Log.e("MusicPlayer", "Playing: " + path);
                try {

                    Notification notification = new Notification(
                            R.drawable.playbackstart, path, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    nm.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);

                    mp.reset();
                    mp.setDataSource(path);
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start(); 
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                            System.out.println("Hi i am at the End");

                        }
                    });
                }catch {expression}
```

Comment: @Sen: I have wav files to play, not mp3. Can MediaPlayer play wav files too?

Comment: @Sen: The reason I used create() is because the documentation itself says so. The link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.view.SurfaceHolder)

Comment: @Sriram :__Can MediaPlayer play wav files too? Yes.. __ please refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: @Sriram: Did you try my implementation. It can also do the same thing you want.

Comment: @Sen: I tried the code above. It fails on prepare(). This is also the reason why I switched over to create(). Is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: Why dont you just try your playFunction() alone on your onCreate without bringing in the button complexities? So that it easy to debug the function alone.

Comment: @Sen: Moved all the MediaPlayer related functions to onCreate(), removed the buttons and still no luck. If I use create(), then it fails on create(), and if I use prepare(), then I get an IOException on prepare().

Comment: @Sen: I think I may have figured it out. I do not have an image on the system for the sd card. I need to create an image for the sd card and then maybe I can use it. Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: @Sen: nope. that did not solve the problem either. the player seems to fail on prepare() with status 0x1. I have seen a lot of people face the same errors but no real solution/explanation so far.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, you can't use onPrepare because mp.prepare() is called inside MediaPlayer.create(). The simpliest code can be something like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, streamUri);
mp.start();
```

If you want something more elaborated, you can try this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, streamUri);        
if(mp == null) {            
    Log.v(this.toString(), "Create() on MediaPlayer failed.");       
} else {
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
          //here you should call the methods to release memory
          mp.stop();
          mp.release();
      }
    });
    mp.start();

}
```

Tell me if it helped you.

PD: Is better if you use a device for testing rather than a simulator. Some classes don't work properly there (MediaPlayer can't reproduce video in simulators) and I don't remember if it supports audio.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I have tried what you said in a background service, but I got this message in the logcat: 
   `"Create() on MediaPlayer failed."`

Comment: This means it's still null, so how can I fix that?

Comment: What is your streamUri? Check it

Comment: This is my stream: STREAM_MUSIC

Comment: I am playing the music in a background service

Comment: If you are successfully playing the music, then you should not be getting `"Create() on MediaPlayer failed"`. `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri)`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem: You are calling the `MediaPlayer.create(...)` method, and it returns `null`, meaning the creation of a `MediaPlayer instance` failed. According to the accepted answer of this post [MediaPlayer.create() always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882851/mediaplayer-create-always-returns-null) it is due to a `corrupted audio file`.

I also have an issue, where the sound gets played but on rare occasions the create() method also returns null. I use sounds in a turn based game, after each turn a sound is played. I always call the create method, start the player and release it when it's done. That happens every turn and like once in 300 turns the create method returns null... So in my case it must be something else. In yours it could probably have something to do with the corruption of the mp3 file.