# MediaPlayer.create() always returns null

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have used the mediaplayer before, and I have never had this problem. Whenever I try to use MediaPlayer.create(), the method gives me null, and I can't play my sounds. Is there anything that I am missing?

```
public class Game extends Activity
{
    private MediaPlayer mp = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.sound);
    }
}
```

my sound.mp3 is in my raw folder, which I placed in there by draging my sound to the folder in eclipse. Please help, since I have played sound before, this is really bugging me :(

Comment: Can you try with a different sound file? I think this one may be corrupt.

Comment: That was totally the issue! Thanks alot. Answer and I will credit you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [create()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) API returns null if it somehow failed.

The reason in this case is due to a corrupt mp3 file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was the emulator (AVD)

Make sure that you also test it using a real Android device

or, create a new AVD profile with better spec and newer Android version

What seems to always work regardless of which AVD is using 128kbps mp3 audio file