# NullPointer with only the gplay report

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, google-play

hello i've an app in the gplay store, and from 200 players there are 2 crashes:

this one:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ch.xyxy.datapp/ch.xyxy.datapp.MainScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ch..xyxy.datapp.MainScreen.onCreate(MainScreen.java:239)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5302)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2228)
... 11 more
```

this is line 238 & 239 in onCreate

```
  mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainScreen.this, R.raw.nova);
        mp.start();
```

and this one (this is in an activity where the player has to press many times on a button)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ch..xyxy.datapp.Game.onClick(Game.java:298)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5506)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and these are the lines around 298:

```
MediaPlayer over1;
//....
over1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.over1);
//....

 if(v == gameover){
 over1.start();
}
```

I honestly don't know how to solve this because on my device it's working perfect and in this way I cannot provoke this error for me to know where exactly it's happening. So why is this error showing up?

Comment: Post your `onClick` and `onCreate` methods in their respective classes. They are throwing NPE obviously

Comment: Show us lines 239 in `onCreate` and 298 in `onClick`

Comment: Thanks. edited. seems like some problems with the media player...?

Comment: @EmanuelGraf Yeah, the `MediaPlayer.create(..)` method is returning `null` so therefore `mp.start()` and `over1.start()` both throw an NPE

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882851/mediaplayer-create-always-returns-null) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811466/android-mediaplayer-create-returns-null)

Comment: Seems like your media may be in a format that some - but apparently not all - devices support.  If it is a frequent problem you should fix that, while if it is fairly rare, you could just catch it and let the user know their device isn't supported by your app (assuming it isn't a paid one)

Comment: now, as I'm focusing on it, logcat says: should have subtile controller already set    is this the error?